# SonarQube v8.2 Error: While Scanning Simple .net code (javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory etc...)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

As I am new to SonarQube Code scanner so need assistance as got stuck with below issue in SonarQube v 8.2.

SonarQube is installed on Windows server and I am trying to scan code form my client machine i.e Window 10.

I am executing from Developer Command Prompt for VS 2015

So far as per suggested solutions, I have updated my client machine with Java version to 11 SE, JDK 12, also placed apache-ant-1.10.7-bin and add in path, then also try by adding xercesImpl-2.12.1.jar in ant path but nothing work out so far.

JRE version: jre-8u251-windows-i586

I try to find out solution on forums but unable to find so... Kindly guide how to get rid from this error and run scanner successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Detail Steps are as below:

Initial two steps went fine i.e
(1)
Execute First Command: **SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"SomeConsoleapplication"**
Result are fine as below
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
00:55:48.687  Updating build integration targets...
00:55:48.703  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
00:55:51.86  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for cs...
00:55:51.864  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
00:55:52.718  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for vbnet...
00:55:52.722  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
00:55:52.822  Pre-processing succeeded.

(2) 
Execute Second command: msbuild (to build project)

Results: Build succeeded. (with warnings but all fine)

(3) **Problematic Step**

SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end

Results:

SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.2
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Default properties file was found at C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\msbuild-sonarqube-runner\tools\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\msbuild-sonarqube-runner\tools\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value of -Xmx1024m
Calling the SonarQube Scanner...
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\msbuild-sonarqube-runner\tools\sonar-scanner-3.1.0.1141\bin..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: D:\Azure DevOps\Repos\Demo New Project.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.1.0.1141
INFO: Java 12 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
INFO: SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
INFO: User cache: C:\Users**********.sonar\cache
INFO: SonarQube server 8.2.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

**INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1.242s
INFO: Final Memory: 3M/14M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created
ERROR: Caused by: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created
ERROR: Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
01:06:30.517  Creating a summary markdown file...
01:06:30.521  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1**

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved by removing Read-Only property of SonatQube Server website.

Now it is running perfectly.